# CSS Floats and General Confusion

Tags: css, css-float

My apologies if this too basic of a question but CSS is boggling me.  I think I'm doing something that CSS is supposed to do easily but it is simply not working the way I read the documentation.

Here's my example.  It's been massively simplified but the basic problem remains.  I'm sure this is some core misconception on my part, I just don't know where it lies.

Here's the goal:

[image: Tabs with transparent separator between them]

Here's what I get now:
[image: Where I am at]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="line-wrapper">
    <div id="block-nice-menus-1">
        <ul id="nice-menu-1">
            <li><span title="Departments" class="nolink">Departments</span>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="block-imageblock-40">
        <img src="http://www.kallenconsulting.com/home/files/top-menu-swish.png"
        alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="block-imageblock-42">
        <img src="http://www.kallenconsulting.com/home/files/Transparent-4x6.png"
        alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
/* -- nice-menu-1 is Main Menu -- */
#line-wrapper {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
#block-nice-menus-1 {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    background: #d6b982;
}
#nice-menu-1 {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    color: #000;
    background: #d6b982;
    line-height: 2.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nice-menu-1 ul, #nice-menu-1 li {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-color: #e11837;
}
#block-imageblock-40 {
    /* top-menu-swish */
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
}
#block-imageblock-42 {
    /* top-menu-leading-line */
    bottom: 0px;
    height:6px;
    width:100%;
    background: #d6b982;
}
```

I can't get the floats right (I know, Yet Another Float Question).  The main issue is that this is going to be a menu with a variable number of items, so as the menu grows, ("Departments" now, but later "Departments", "Services", "Sections", etc.) it should push to the left, reducing the length of the line  I can't use a fixed length on the leading line (#block-imageblock-42).  Also, the menu items will have separators, so I can't just full-width things.  This needs to be done in pure CSS, no jQuery or other JS.

Here's my JSfiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/zjfsy/

**UPDATE:** *I have modified the question to be more specific per the requests of folks trying to help.  The "goal" image at the top has been updated to more accurately reflect the issue.  One thing I really want to make clear is that this specific instance is not so important.  I already doctored up a position:absolute fix that will hold for the short term.  My desire is to understand better why this is so hard.  I have three containers.  I want two of them to float right and the third to expand to fill the space from the last container to the edge of the page.  It seems like this is what float was supposed to do.  I assume this is some base misunderstanding on my part.*

*Anyway.  Here's more constraints:*

1. *The leading bar needs to expand to fill the empty space between the
   left side and the swish.*
2. *Each of the tabs needs to have a separator that allows the background through.*
3. *The number of the tabs is variable, based on client choices -- which
   can change regularly.*
4. *I can't really change the structure of the HTML, other than
   modifying it with CSS.*

And again, all help is *very* much appreciated.

Comment: i looked at your code.. I just want to make sure I know exactly what you want to accomplish before I give you a solution.. can you please update your question with how you want it to look like if the menu grows (ie departments, services sections etc) along with the separators? b/c as it stands the tab ending for each button will just blend into the next button.. so the buttons will look like they're text in one big blog apart from the rest one.. so if you can include that gif i promise you I'll get you something working asap

Comment: asked another way.. will each menu item have that tab image at the end? or will it only be attached to the last item in the list?

Comment: mmm.. so i can't change the html eh? that's pretty restrictive.. lemme see what I can do..

Comment: Hey man.. Please lemme know if my updated answer was correct or not.. It took me quite a while to get it done.

Comment: @abbood I haven't forgotten and it looks right.  In the fiddle, it seems to work perfectly.  My issue is really wanting to know what I was doing wrong.  And right now, I don't have the time to dig in.  Later tonight I'll dig in and try to figure out my mistake.  But I'll go ahead and mark yours as the answer.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: hey man really appreciate it.. regarding understanding why your code didn't work.. lemme say this: i strongly recommend you read the book [CSS the missing manual](http://www.amazon.com/CSS-Missing-David-Sawyer-McFarland/dp/0596802447).. too often devs new to css underestimate it b/c of its apparent simplicity.. but css can be very frustrating for the trial and error approach.. IHO it merits being studied.. a weekend with that book is all you need! please let me know though if you have any specific questions. Again, thanks for your approval of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/abbood/b56Vq/ (never used jsfiddle before.. so sorry if i did this wrong, or if i was supposed to fork your project)

here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="betterStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><div></div><div>Departments</div></li>
                <li><div></div><div>Services</div></li>
                <li><div></div><div>Sections</div></li> 
                <li><div></div><div>stuff</div></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

//betterStyle.css

```
#wrapper {
    height: 2.5em;
    background-color: #e0203b;
    background-image: url('http://s11.postimage.org/a1jmymlgv/bage_Box.png');            
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;  
}

ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    float: right ;
    display: inline-block;        
}

/* text */
ul li div:nth-child(2) {        
    line-height: 2.5em;
    line-weight: bold;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #d6b982;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

/* image */
ul li div:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url('http://s8.postimage.org/b2qycoatd/top_menu_swish.png');
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    float: left;


    width: 53px;
    height: 40px;
    line-weight: bold;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;        
}
```

**notes:**

- i created my own [image](http://s11.postimage.org/a1jmymlgv/bage_Box.png)  and I linked to it using some image hosting service.
- you can add as many tabs as you want (i assumed that each tab will have that image attached to it.. i wasn't sure how you wanted the final thing to look like (the right edges look too sharp).. but i'm sure you can adjust it to your liking.. when adding extra tabs the horizontal line shrinks.. i think that's what you meant when you said *so as the menu grows,  it should push to the left, reducing the length of the line*

[image]

**update:**

Here is the updated answer without changing a line in the html: http://jsfiddle.net/abbood/SkxkC/ (for some reason there is a bump under the folder image in jsfiddle.. i tested it on mac chrome/safari/firefox and they worked fine.. lemme know if it isn't working perfectly for you though)

html (pretty much same.. just added a couple of tabs just for fun):

```
    <body>
        <div id="line-wrapper">
            <div id="block-nice-menus-1">
                <ul id="nice-menu-1">
                    <li><span title="Departments" class="nolink">Departments</span>

                    </li>
                    <li><span title="Departments" class="nolink">Services</span>

                    </li>
                    <li><span title="Departments" class="nolink">Classes</span>

                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
            <div id="block-imageblock-40">
                <img src="http://www.kallenconsulting.com/home/files/top-menu-swish.png"
                alt="" />
            </div>
            <div id="block-imageblock-42">
                <img src="http://www.kallenconsulting.com/home/files/Transparent-4x6.png"
                alt="" />
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
```

css:

```
/* -- nice-menu-1 is Main Menu -- */
#line-wrapper {
    background-color: #ff0000;  /* red */
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
}

#line-wrapper div {
    background-color: #ff0000;  /* red */
}
#block-nice-menus-1 {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    background: #d6b982;
}
#nice-menu-1 {
    display: block;

    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    color: #000;

    line-height: 2.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nice-menu-1 ul {
    padding: 0;
        background-color: #ff0000;  /* red */
}
#nice-menu-1 ul, #nice-menu-1 li {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-color: #e11837;
}

#nice-menu-1 li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2em;
    background: #d6b982;    /* bage */
    height: 40px;
}
#block-imageblock-40 {
    /* top-menu-swish */
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
}
#block-imageblock-42 
{
    /* top-menu-leading-line */
    bottom: 0px;
    height:6px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #d6b982 !important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, @abbood.  I've modified the question to be more clear.  Check out the UPDATE in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I a have also done something similar that does not use the position:relative feature for the #line-wrapper since that may cause you some problems when you implement it.

See http://jsfiddle.net/zjfsy/

```
#block-imageblock-42 {
/* top-menu-leading-line */
height:6px;
width:100%;
background: #d6b982;
position:absolute;
margin-top:34px;
}

#line-wrapper {   
display: block;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Hope this helps!  (I am definitely going to vote wxactly's answer up since it is a better answer than mine since it doesn't require "hard coding" with magic number margins, etc.  Definitely use his answer if you can, but now at least you have two different ways.